# Python Logging: Specifying converter attribute of a log formatter in config file

Tags: python, logging, config, converters, formatter

I'd like to have all timestamps in my log file to be UTC timestamp. When specified through code, this is done as follows:

```
import logging
import time

myHandler = logging.FileHandler('mylogfile.log', 'a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s:%(lineno)4s: %(message)-80s')
formatter.converter = time.gmtime

myHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

myLogger = logging.getLogger('MyApp')
myLogger.addHandler(myHandler)

myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
myLogger.info('here we are')
```

I'd like to move away from the above 'in-code' configuration to a config file based mechanism.

Here's the config file section for the formatter:

```
[handler_MyLogHandler]
args=("mylogfile.log", "a",)
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
```

Now, how do I specify the converter attribute (time.gmtime) in the above section?

Edit: The above config file is loaded thus:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('myLogConfig.conf')
```

Comment: What parses that config file ? There is obviously something missing from this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Thomas. Have added the detail to the qn.

Comment: I updated your code example so it actually runs and logs.  Always provide full code samples.

Comment: Your config is incomplete; here's the exception I get when loading it: ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, there is no way of doing this using the configuration file, other than having e.g. a

```
class UTCFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter = time.gmtime
```

and then using a `UTCFormatter` in the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Here Vinay's solution applied to the logging.basicConfig:

```
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(filename='junk.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
logging.info('A message.')
```